# How to setup G Suite for a domain with name servers of GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, mx-record

I'm setting G suite for my domain with custom DNS from IPAGE, and I use GCP for hosting my website, so I changed the Name servers to point at my project in GCP. What I want here is to setup a Gmail with G Suite.

I already verified the domain name for G suite and it is activated. Also I added the mx-records google provided me with after deleting all the old ones from IPAGE.

I expected this to work but and I will be able to receive email but the g suite admin panel displays this "Whoops! You indicated earlier that you changed your MX records to point to Google, but it's been over 48 hours and they still don't point to our servers. This might mean you made a typing error or some other mistake. That's ok. You can fix this by changing your records again." and I No MX records found. So what is happening here, why google is not reading MX records from IPAGE? Should I add them from GCP instead because my Name servers point to there?

Comment: Double check that the DNS servers listed at your Domain Registrar point to the DNS servers that you are actually configuring. Use an online tool such as MxToolbox to test your DNS settings and find errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mx records` should be added where your name servers point, so in your case add them on GCP.
To do that go to the project on GCP account then navigate to `Network Services --> Cloud DNS`, click on the already created zone and add a new `mx record` set. Click `Add items` to add all the records there.